# The maximum in each row

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalscript, delphi, turbo-pascal

I have a question for you. I need to write the maximum element in each line. For example, my table :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

I want to get 4,8,12
I tried but no result:

```
Program Lab2;
type A=array[1..5,1..5] of integer;
var x:A;
i,j,s,max:integer;
Begin
 writeln('Write date:');
 for i:=1 to 5 do
  for j:=1 to 5 do
    read(x[i,j]);

 for i:=1 to 5 do
  for j:=1 to 5 do
  begin
   max:=x[i,1];
    if (max<x[i,j]) then max:=x[i,j];
   writeln(max);
  end;
 readln;
```

Please help me
end.

Comment: Your writeln should be in the outer for, same with max:=x[i,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just three little mistakes:

1) `if (max<x[i,j])` should be outside the second for loop, because you want initialize the max value  only one time per row.

2) `writeln(max);` should be outside the second for loop, you want to print the value only one time per row.

3)  <del>`read(x[i,j]);` I reccomend to be `readln (x[i,j])` because with read you only read one character, with readln you red characters till you find a new line character,  and that will allow you to enter numbers with more than two digits.</del>

<sup>This only make sense for strings, you can use `read` or `readln` with integers</sup>

Also I advice you to write the key word `begin` in the same line where you write a contol structure (for,while,if,etc), because in this way it's more similar to the C coding style convention, one of the most populars coding styles I guess. And also is better for you if you try to keep a similar coding style for any language.

so the code will be:

```
Program Lab2;
const SIZE=3;
type A=array [1..SIZE,1..SIZE] of integer;
var x:A;
i,j,max:integer;
Begin
  writeln('Write date:');
  for i:=1 to SIZE do begin
    for j:=1 to SIZE do begin
      readln(x[i,j]);
    end;
  end;
  for i:=1 to SIZE do begin
    max:=x[i,1];
    for j:=1 to SIZE do begin
      if (max<x[i,j]) then begin
        max:=x[i,j];
      end;
    end;
    writeln('the max value of the row ',i ,' is ',max);
end;
 readln;
 readln;
end.
```

Comment: `with read you only read one character` - it is wrong at least for integers.

Comment: you are right, Long time without programming in pascal, I'm sorry